# Nested objects in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, function, object, jquery

I have following piece of code

```
(function($) {
       $.object1=function(){
         $.method=function(){
       }
     };

      $.object2 = function(){

     };


 })(jquery);
```

I want to access method of object1 from the object2. Is it possible?? I tried with `$.object1.method();` But it didnt work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Better way,

```
var object1 = function(){}
object.prototype = {
method:function(){}
};

var object2 = function(){
var obj1 = new object1();
obj1.method();
}

$(function(){
object2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MMAF/4/)

```
$.object1 =  {
    method: function () {
        alert("hi from o1.method");
    }
};


$.object2 = {
    method: function () {
         $.object1.method();
    }
};  

$( function() {
       $.object2.method();
});
```

Comment: Need to put in jquery block